# How to use DaprServer instance for exposing API endpoints and receiving events in Javascript at the same time?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dapr

Given the following JavaScript application running on Node on the Dapr runtime:

```
import { DaprServer, CommunicationProtocolEnum } from "@dapr/dapr";
import express from "express";

const myApp = express();

myApp.get("/my-custom-endpoint", (req, res) => {
  res.send({ msg: "My own express app!" });
});

const daprServer = new DaprServer({
      serverHost: "127.0.0.1",
      serverPort: "3000",
      serverHttp: myApp,
    });

await daprServer.pubsub.subscribe("pubsub", "messages", async (messageId) => {
        console.log(`Subscriber received: ${JSON.stringify(messageId)}`)
    });

await daprServer.start();
```

In this example, we would like to use the `daprServer` instance to both:

- Expose HTTP API endpoints
- Listen to events from the `pubsub` pubsub on the `messages` topic

However when running this via `dapr run --app-id background-with-api --app-port 3000 -- node main.js`, **event listening seems to be disabled.**

The same setup is actually feasible with C# and asp.net core, since [node now supports threads](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html) I don't see why this doesn't work with Javascript?

Am I missing something ?